# can't covert css to rtl using javascript library

Tags: javascript, rtlcss

I am beginner in JavaScript and I am trying to use [rtlcss library](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) to conver css files from ltr to rtl. I am using this code but it displays 2 errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>convert css to rtl</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/rtlcss/src/rtlcss.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="source_textarea" placeholder="place your css" ></textarea>
    <button id="convert_btn">Convert</button>
    <textarea id="result_textarea"></textarea>
    <script>
        (function myfunction() {
            rtlcss = require('rtlcss');
            var output = rtlcss.process('css/main.css');
            console.log(output);
            $("#result_textarea").val(output);
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe i am doing something wrong, it's not library problem.. so anyone can help?

Comment: Do you understand what the error means?

Comment: Well nor did I really, but I don't think you can use `require`- This is because require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript. from link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: I only briefly looked over the library but I don't think you use it on the client side

Comment: @haakym then, how i can use it ?

Comment: Take a look at Node JS, you should be using NPM (node package manager) to install RTLCSS. I think the library converts the file rather than doing it on the fly in the browser.

Comment: @haakym reasonable words, thanks

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could be of some help

Answer (score 1):

This is a node package, as @haakym mentioned, you should be using NPM (node package manager). For more details on how to install and use NPM, follow the [Getting Started](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node) guide.

If you want to use it in the browser, you can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/); it lets you require('modules') in the browser by bundling up all of your dependencies.

After you have node/npm setup complete, do the following:

- From the command line, run these commands to install [RTLCSS](https://github.com/MohammadYounes/rtlcss) and [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

  ```
  npm install rtlcss
  npm install -g browserify
  ```
- Create a file with the following contents and save it as  `main.js` :

  ```
  rtlcss = require('rtlcss');
  ```
- Run this command to create a browser usable bundle:

  ```
  browserify main.js -o bundle.js
  ```
- Include the resulting script in your page:

  ```
  <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  ```

That's all, Now you'll be able to use it in the browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>convert css to rtl</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="source_textarea" placeholder="place your css" ></textarea>
    <button id="convert_btn">Convert</button>
    <textarea id="result_textarea"></textarea>
    <script>
    $('button').click(function(){
      var output = rtlcss.process($('#source_textarea').val());
      $("#result_textarea").val(output);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Online Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tfg0pa2q/)